# Как сделать двойной текст в кнопке?

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать в кнопке двойной текст у которых разные размеры . Пробовал через &#10 понял что это не то.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `SpannableStringBuilder` и `RelativeSizeSpan` , в итоге
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Button button = findViewById( R.id.button );
String text_top = "Newbie";
String text_bottom = "Just getting started";
SpannableStringBuilder ss_builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text_top+"\n"+text_bottom);
RelativeSizeSpan relative_size_span_2 = new RelativeSizeSpan(2.0f); // меняйте относительный размер здесь 
ss_builder.setSpan( relative_size_span_2, 0, text_top.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE );
button.setText( ss_builder );
```

Answer (score 4):

Я лично вижу два варианта:

1. Сетить html в текст кнопки
2. Сделать view который будет соответствовать вашим требованиям

Первый пункт:

```
button1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b><big>" + "Title" + "</big></b>" +  "<br />" + 
        "<small>" + "subtitle" + "</small>" + "<br />"));
```

Второй пункт - создаете в месте где вам нужна кнопка вместо Button макет Linear layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="NewBie"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Some text"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

сетите ему кастомный фон из папки drawable у которого будут закругленные углы и все что вам нужно. Вешаете слушатель в активности на нажатия и будет у вас своя кастомная вьюха